# Proxy to visit and stay on “CURLOPT_URL” 60s/120s or more time

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I'm using this below code to auto visit url using proxy. At once load many proxy to visit url.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $mt_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,  $referer[array_rand($referer)]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent[array_rand($userAgent)]);
```

When I'm checking my stats I can see visits count and refers sites but when visit url, not stay on visited url sometimes.

Is there any option to make this script stay on CURLOPT_URL for 60s/120s or more time for each proxy? Thanks.

Comment: no one is here to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try the curl flag `--retry` which tries the request again backing off slowly. The retry interval is configurable as well as the maximum time to wait. The [curl manpage](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) covers `--retry` at length.